# How to check if my OpenLayers Map has finished to render?

Tags: openlayers, export

I am exporting an image from the current view of my map, but sometimes it exports an incomplete image like this:

[image]

And I need the image looks like this:

[image]

This second image I took a screen shot of my map to illustrate what I need.

I'm using OpenLayers.

Comment: There's `postrender` event but it doesn't ensure the tiles are visible on the screen.

Comment: I'm already using it, but I'd like to know if there something I can do to ensure everything has finished render before take a screenshot. Is there something I can do?

Comment: what about the check jquery's `when`, `done`?